# How to get bounding boxes for characters in TrOCR model?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, huggingface-transformers

I wanted to know how can we get bounding boxes for each character in the line image if using a TrOCR model.

This is the basic OCR  code:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image

processor = TrOCRProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-base-handwritten")

# load image from the IAM dataset
url = "https://fki.tic.heia-fr.ch/static/img/a01-122-02.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw).convert("RGB")

pixel_values = processor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
generated_ids = model.generate(pixel_values)

generated_text = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]
```

I came across one issue in Pillow (https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3921) where someone suggested this solution to get coordinates for each character:

```
image = Image.new("RGB", (200, 100))
font_filepath = "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf"
font_size = 50

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_filepath, font_size)

xy = (40, 20)
text = "hello"

draw.text(xy, text, font=font)

for i, char in enumerate(text):
    right, bottom = font.getsize(text[:i+1])
    width, height = font.getmask(char).size
    right += xy[0]
    bottom += xy[1]
    top = bottom - height
    left = right - width
    
    draw.rectangle((left, top, right, bottom), None, "#f00")

image.save("out.png")
```

I'm curious how can we adapt this code to get bounding box coordinates for the TrOCR model. I'd appreciate any help.